# C#: Which is the best hook to use to monitor multiple-key shortcuts globally?

Tags: c#

C#: Which is the best hook to use to monitor multiple-key shortcuts globally?

There is LowLevelKeyboardProc and KeyboardProc. I want to monitor key-combinations such as,
Alt+Q globally in Windows and perform an action based on Alt+Q being pressed. Which hook would be the best option to use and how would I go upon detecting if all the keys in the hotkey are currently being held down as opposed to monitoring each key one by one in the hook callback?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a choice, WH_KEYBOARD_LL is the only one you can write in C#.  WH_KEYBOARD requires writing a DLL that can be injected in another process.  Not possible with managed code, the CLR cannot be initialized properly.

Also consider RegisterHotKey(). Sample code [is there](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/2622427d-1e15-4f30-b01d-57b0ba054f5c/), you'll find C# further down the page.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the answer by Hans Passant, technically there is no way except attaching to `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook. Nevertheless there is a managed library [MouseKeyHook as nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=MouseKeyHook) which gives you a convenience managed wrapper. [Source code on github](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook).

Recently support for detecting shortcuts, key combinations and sequences was added. Here is a usage example:

```
void DoSomething()
{
    Console.WriteLine("You pressed UNDO");
}

Hook.GlobalEvents().OnCombination(new Dictionary<Combination, Action>
{
    {Combination.FromString("Control+Z"), DoSomething},
    {Combination.FromString("Shift+Alt+Enter"), () => { Console.WriteLine("You Pressed FULL SCREEN"); }}
});
```

For more information see: [Detecting Key Combinations and Seuqnces](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook/blob/vNext/keycomb.md)